# Should I make an array to store user ids or create new tables?

Tags: mysql, arrays

I'm trying to make an image uploading website and want to create a like system for the images that are uploaded. So should I create an array containing the image id's of all the images liked by a particular user and store this array in the row of that user in the users' table or should I create a new table for every image that is uploaded and store the usernames of all the people that have liked that image in this table?

Efficiency-wise, which is better?
Thanks!

Comment: Create a pivot table and store the user_id and image_id and probably more info if you prefer

Comment: Always ask yourself, "what if I had a million" images, or users, or users liking a single image. If you ask yourself that question you'll quickly rule out both the alternatives you proposed.

Comment: So, Mr.O.Jones, is there a third alternative for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you should probably use a table, something like this :

Table Users

> 1. ID
> 2. NAME

Table Images

> 1. ID
> 2. IMAGE URL

TABLE Image_likes

> 1. ID
> 2. USER_ID - the id of the user
> 3. IMAGE_ID - the id of the image.

So in this case, whenever a user likes an image, a record is created in the table Image_likes that tells us which user liked which image.

Comment: Won't this make the loading of the webpage very slow? Pardon me but I'm very new to MySql. Thanks!

Comment: No, not at all. The "image_likes" table has only integer values, making it super fast.